# Cleaning up birth years 2000 in my Address Book

Tags: macos, applescript, contacts

A few years ago (or actually, more likely, in 2000), for some reason, `birthdays` that didn't have a `birth year` (but did and do have correct month and day) were automatically given the `birth year` 2000 in my Address Book. There are hundreds of them (among thousands which are fine).

Is there a way to select these cards, perhaps by Smart Group or something similar, so that I may manually remove the `birth year` 2000?

---

NB: I just might also be able to run an AppleScript with a little help. :) OS X 10.8.5 installed.

Comment: My address book has a bunch of people with a birth year of 1900!

Comment: @DanielLawson The script below by adayzdone (v1) works like a charm. What I did: Open Address Book, click All Contacts, close Address Book, close the internet connection, copy-paste into AppleScript Editor, press Compile, press Run, wait until "Running..." disappears. Address Book is now open with the cards with 2000 selected. Put those in a group for further work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set targetYear to "2000"
set targetGroup to {}

tell application "Address Book"
    set thePeople to every person whose birth date ≠ missing value
    repeat with aPerson in thePeople
        set birthYear to (aPerson's birth date)
        if my yearCheck(birthYear, targetYear) then set end of targetGroup to (contents of aPerson)
    end repeat
    if targetGroup ≠ {} then set selection to targetGroup
    activate
end tell

on yearCheck(theDate, theYear)
    if theYear = (year of theDate as text) then return true
    return false
end yearCheck
```

---

*Added by the OP for novices like him.* This works. What I did: Open Address Book, click All Contacts, close Address Book, close the Internet connection (just to be sure), copy-paste the above script into AppleScript Editor, press Compile, press Run, wait until "Running..." disappears. Address Book is now open with the cards with 2000 selected. Put those in a Group for further work...

Comment: It won't change anything. It will select the cards.

Comment: Works like a charm! I hate to ask this, but... It turns out there are 632 cards with the year 2000. Even more than I suspected. Could you please please please make the script remove the years, but keep months and days? Did I say please?

Comment: I don't think you can remove the year. I tried doing it manually and it doesn't work in 10.6.8

Comment: I think I can in 10.8.5, at least it appears that I can change "December 22, 2000" to "December 22" (but _not_ to "Frog 22"). (Perhaps I'll ask another question on the site.) Well, I do have the selection now in a Group, so that's a huge start. Many, many thanks!

Comment: FYI: markhunte figured out that setting the year to 1604 makes the year "disappear".

Comment: Ha ... I think that is the strangest solution I have seen!

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally posted an answer here on this question meant for:

[Removing only birth years from a group in my Address Book](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101717/removing-only-birth-years-from-a-group-in-my-address-book)

Since it is related I will leave a link to the other question.

Comment: Great! 1604. I'll give it a go later today. Thanks, looks good.

Comment: I posted the answer on your other question where it was meant to go. If it works out can you accept or comment on that one. Cheers