# Removing only birth years from a group in my Address Book

Tags: macos, applescript, contacts

A lot of my contacts (600+) had somehow got their birth *years* set to 2000. Their birth months and days are correct, but the 2000 is wrong.

With the tremendous help I got [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101709/48249), I was able to get them in one group (which I called 2K).

I would like to remove the birth *years* from those cards, while retaining birth *months* and *days*.

On my OS X 10.8.5 it can even be done manually, but not on adayzdone's 10.6.8.

Can anybody provide a script (for 10.8.5)?

---

So, I would like to turn

[image]

into

[image]

using AppleScript rather than doing it manually. And not just November 10.

Comment: You used this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101692/cleaning-up-birth-years-2000-in-my-address-book/101709#101709 to fill in the 2000 in all contacts without date. So now you have 2000. That was what you wanted in first place. Now you want to remove that date again?

Comment: @Buscar웃 No, _that_ script didn't fill in 2000. That script _selected_ all contacts with a 2000 birthdate. Unfortunately, it doesn't take action on them (like removing the 2000 from the birthdate, but keeping month and day.)

Comment: To what end do you need to do this.  The date is still going to be wrong? With no year. Which may have unforeseen problems further down the line if this is the built in birthdays field. Would it not be best to move the known day and month to the notes and then remove the birthdate. Until a time when you have the correct dates

Comment: @markhunte Well, I get Calendar alerts, which I appreciate. But I don't like many of them to state, falsely, that "tomorrow, X is having his 13th birthday" or something like it. It at looks like the year-less data is accepted.

Comment: I accidentally put the answer on your old question. This will do what you want

Comment: @markhunte Got it. I'll accept the answer here when the final results (of my running the thing) are in later today.

Comment: Ta. let me know if there are any probs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.
   Since you have your group already you group.

```
set targetGroup to "BD" 
tell application "Contacts"
    set thePeople to people of group targetGroup
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in thePeople
        set this_item to item i of thePeople
        set thisDate to birth date of this_item
        set year of thisDate to 1604

        set birth date of this_item to thisDate
        save
    end repeat


end tell
```

I tried to set the year to "" . But it changes the whole date. day and month to something else.

So I checked what a yearless birth date 'date' looked like and they all had 1604 in the year position.

setting the year to this seems to work.